# What does "-" mean before a column in where

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, where

I was seeing an Oracle `view` `sys.dba_audit_trail`, and I came across the following `where` clause:

```
where   aud.action#     = act.action    (+)
  and - aud.logoff$dead = spm.privilege (+)
  and   aud.logoff$dead = aom.option#   (+)
  and - aud.priv$used   = spx.privilege (+);
```

I would like to know what `-` means.

And if possible, know if I can do it with ANSI SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It just negates the value in the column.

For example:

```
 with data1 as ( select 1 as col1 from dual)
 select -col1, col1
 from data1
 where -col1 = -1;
```

... returns `-1`,`1`.

[Fiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=142e5071066b185567436cfa3c7b6af0).